# Custom styled select box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a script for custom styled select boxes, and as I have plenty entries inside one of select box I need to make but am stuck in creation of scrolling function ( a script that counts the number items and if it's over X then need to bre some Overflow attribute to the UL that the script is creating.) any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such direct option for overflow control, browser will automatically manage with the document height.

In order to do that, you can use [jQuery Dropdown Replacement](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropdownReplacement) and apply skins from the link you have.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good way to do it ! ^^ I just made it few seconds ago ;)

**HTML**

```
<div class="styledSelect">
                <span class="styledSelectValue"></span>
                <select name="type">
                    <option value="">Par type de propriété</option>
                    <option value="choix2">choix2</option>
                    <option value="choix3">choix3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.styledSelect{/*your css for the background image... it will be the body of your select*/}
.styledSelect select{/*your css with opacity:0;*/}
.styledSelectValue{/*the css of the received value*/}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.styledSelect').each(function(){
            selectValue = $(this).children("select").val();
            if(selectValue == ""){selectValue = $(this).children("select").children("option:eq(0)").text();}
            $(this).children(".styledSelectValue").text(selectValue);
        });
        $('.styledSelect select').change(function(){
            selectValue = $(this).val();
            if(selectValue == ""){selectValue = $(this).children("option:eq(0)").text();}
            $(this).parent(".styledSelect").children(".styledSelectValue").text(selectValue);
        });
```

It's the best way i found ;)